# Split text in large textblock and insert into two seperate table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to read question and answer from a large textbox and using explode to split the questions and answer and then insert into two table

Data

> The Q is ___ W.|(a)(0)|(b)(0)|(c)(1)|(d)(0)|(e)(0)|(f)(0)|
>
> The W is _________ Q and Z.|(a)(0)|(b)(0)|(c)(0)|(d)(1)|(e)(0)|

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $Code = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['qrc']);
    $linesOfData = explode('\n',$Code);

    foreach($linesOfData as $lineOfData) {
        $arrayOfValues = explode('|',$lineOfData);
        foreach($arrayOfValues as $value) {

            $q  = !isset($value[0]) ? trim($value[0]) : null; // question
            $a   = !isset($value[1]) ? trim($value[1]) : null; //answer
            $b   = !isset($value[1]) ? trim($value[1]) : null; // right answer

            echo $q;

            //$query = "INSERT INTO question (question) VALUES ('$q')";
            //$mysqli->query($query);

            //$query = "INSERT INTO answer(question_id,answer,is_right_option) values($mysqli->insert_id,'$a',$b')";
            //$mysqli->query($query);
        }
    }
}
```

Before executing the queries..I tried to to echo the output but nothing is displayed.
What am i doing wrong? how to fix it?

Table name: Question

```
╔════╤═════════════════════════════╗
║ id │ question                    ║
╠════╪═════════════════════════════╣
║ 1  │ The Q is ___ W.             ║
╟────┼─────────────────────────────╢
║ 2  │ The W is _________ Q and Z. ║
╚════╧═════════════════════════════╝
```

Table name: Answer

```
╔════╤═════════════╤════════╤═════════════════╗
║ id │ question_id │ answer │ is_right_option ║
╠════╪═════════════╪════════╪═════════════════╣
║ 1  │ 1           │ (a)    │ 0               ║
╟────┼─────────────┼────────┼─────────────────╢
║ 2  │ 1           │ (b)    │ 0               ║
╟────┼─────────────┼────────┼─────────────────╢
║ 3  │ 1           │ (c)    │ 1               ║
╟────┼─────────────┼────────┼─────────────────╢
║ 4  │ 1           │ (d)    │ 0               ║
╚════╧═════════════╧════════╧═════════════════╝
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to just store the right option instead of all the 'not right' ones too?

Comment: Answer column will have real answer like..10%, 12% 56% 13%  for each questions..So is_right_option is use to denote which one is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong.

```
    $q  = !isset($value[0]) ? trim($value[0]) : null; // question
```

This means if `$value[0]` is not set, NOT set, so it is NOT present, then trim the value. Otherwise, this means it IS set, set it to `null`

change it to:

```
  $q  = isset($value[0]) ? trim($value[0]) : null; // question
```

Comment: i did a dumb mistake, I changed it now but when i echo $q,$a,$b.. I get Te()()()()()()\Te()()()()() instead of storing it like this $a = The Q is ___ W. $a=(a),$b=0

Comment: upodate your post with the code you are using now and do a 'print_r($_POST['qrc']);` and add that value as well.

Comment: Here is the updated code..https://3v4l.org/kQ3f8 right now i can' get last line of data. f)  (f). d) does leave the train, d) Ilegal... Something to do with the regex ? Tried debugging it here..http://regexr.com/3dal0 it omits the last line

Comment: It would be better to put the code here. You could use `preg_replace()`. But to be honest I would go for a different approach, that is another issue though. This question was about why nothing showed up. My approach would be to use (multidimensional)arrays in the form you create the input with. Why are those brackets there in the first place if all you are going to do is remove them?